# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENDIF in /home/content error php

Tags: php, html, wordpress

thank guys you fixed the function problem, site is still screwy though tried to debug with psp pad and altova  + dw but did not show up but at least error gone. thanks u got me trouble :-)

==========================

hi i have a WordPress site and its giving me this error :

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENDIF in /home/content/58/5025958/html/wordpress/wp-content/themes/#####/header.php on line 90 .

```
88<ul>
89<?php if ( function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') && dynamic_sidebar(2) ); ?>
90<?php endif; ?>
91</ul>
```

here is the full code :if any help out there i would appreciate it I am stumped 
i know its some thing simple`

```
 <?php
/**
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Default_Theme

 */

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="<?php bloginfo('html_type'); ?>; charset=<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>" />
<title><?php wp_title('&laquo;', true, 'right'); ?> <?php bloginfo('name'); ?></title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" type="text/css" media="screen" />

<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo('pingback_url'); ?>" />
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
<?php
// Checks to see whether it needs a sidebar or not

if ( empty($withcomments) && !is_single() ) {
?>
    #page { background: url("<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/kubrickbg-<?php bloginfo('text_direction'); ?>.jpg") repeat-y top; border: none; }

<?php } else { // No sidebar ?>
    #page { background: url("<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/kubrickbgwide.jpg") repeat-y top; border: none; }

<?php } ?>
</style>
<?php if ( is_singular() ) wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' ); ?>
<?php wp_head(); ?>
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div id="page">
<div id="header" role="banner">

    <div id="headerimg">

        <h1><a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/"></a></h1>

        <div class="description"><?php bloginfo('description'); ?></div>

            <div id="sidebar2" class="g10">
                <ul>
                    <?php if ( function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') && dynamic_sidebar(2) ); ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>


<hr />
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about basic debugging

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php if ( function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') && dynamic_sidebar(2) ); ?>
```

Change trailing ; to :

Answer (score 1):

Use : isntead of ;

```
<ul>
<?php if ( function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') && dynamic_sidebar(2) ): ?>
<?php endif; ?>
</ul>
```